# Showing $e^{\frac{1}{2} (H (2-x)+L x)}-e^{\frac{1}{2} (H x+L (2-x))}-(1-x) \left(e^H-e^L\right)\leq 0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $H>L>0$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, exponential-function

For my research, I'm trying to prove something that ends up depending on whether the expression $e^{\frac{1}{2} (H (2-x)+L x)}-e^{\frac{1}{2} (H x+L (2-x))}-(1-x) \left(e^H-e^L\right)\leq 0$ is true for values of $H>L>0$ and any value of $x$ between 0 and 1.

I'm reasonably certain this is true, but am unsure of how to go about proving it. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c \geqslant 0$ and $0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1,$ then
$$
e^{cy} - e^{-cy} = 2\left(cy + \frac{c^3y^3}{3!} + \frac{c^5y^5}{5!} + \cdots\right)
\leqslant 2y\left(c + \frac{c^3}{3!} + \frac{c^5}{5!} + \cdots\right) =
y(e^{c} - e^{-c}).
$$
Substituting $y = 1 - x$ and $c = (H - L)/2$ gives
$$
e^{(H - L)(1 - x)/2} - e^{(L - H)(1 - x)/2} \leqslant (1 - x)\left(e^{(H - L)/2} - e^{(L - H)/2}\right),
$$
and multiplying through by $e^{(H + L)/2}$ gives
$$
e^{H - (H - L)x/2} - e^{L + (H - L)x/2} \leqslant (1 - x)\left(e^{H} - e^{L}\right),
$$
which is equivalent to the required result.